# Can't implement write() and read() in Character Device Driver

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create a simple character device LKM but I've been stuck for days trying to get my read and write to work correctly. Currently when I do something like:

```
echo hi > /dev/simple_character_device
```

I am able to see I'm writing the correct amount of bytes.

But when I attempt to cat out the contents of that device it will continuously loop hi until reaching a bad address. Currently I'm trying to keep track of how many bytes I've written in a global counter. But that doesn't seem right. Any help on implementing the read and write would be appreciated.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

#define BUFFER 1024
char * buffer_data;

// Count open and closed
size_t current_count;

int my_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
int my_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
ssize_t my_read(struct file *, char __user *, size_t count, loff_t *);
ssize_t my_write(struct file *, const char __user *, size_t count, loff_t *offp); 

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_release,
    .read = my_read,
    .write = my_write
};


int reg_init(void)
{
    // Allocate memory to store information 
    buffer_data = kmalloc(BUFFER, GFP_KERNEL);  // Use Kernel Flag

    register_chrdev(240, "simple_character_device", &fops);
    
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Init Allocating Memory");
    return 0;
}

void reg_exit(void)
{
    // Free and unregister device and data
    kfree(buffer_data);
    unregister_chrdev(240, "simple_character_device");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Deregister Simple Character Device");
}


int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Open File Device.\n");
    return 0;
}

int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Close File Device.\n");
    return 0;
}

ssize_t my_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *offp){
    // Check if we are reading within the Buffer Size
    if(BUFFER - *offp < 0){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Out of buffer range.\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    
    // Check if we fail to copy to user
    if (copy_to_user(buff, buffer_data, current_count) != 0){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to send character to user\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    (*offp) += current_count;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Read %zu bytes.\n", current_count);
    return current_count;
}

ssize_t my_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *offp){
    // We need to get data FROM the user space
    
    // Make sure we are reading within the buffer
    if (*offp >= BUFFER || BUFFER - count < *offp){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "ATTEMPTING TO WRITE TO OUSIDE OF BUFFER!\n");
        return EFAULT;
    }
    
    // Get the amount of bytes from the user
    copy_from_user(buffer_data + *offp, buff, count);

    *offp += count;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Wrote %zu to the device.\n", count);
    current_count = count;
    return current_count;
}
 
module_init(reg_init);
module_exit(reg_exit);
```

Comment: In `my_read()`, don't you need to add `*offp` to `buffer_data` like you do in `my_write()`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with `current_count`, but `my_read()` returns that value. An end-of-file condition is indicated by a return value of 0 when `count` is non-zero. `cat` will keep reading the file until it reaches end-of-file or an error. Also, `my_read()` must not copy more than `count` bytes to `buff` in each call (i.e. it should not access `buff[count]` and beyond).

Comment: I've tried modifying my_read but still no luck. It stops looping now, but doesn't display the output and the count is crazy large. 

 `copy_to_user(buff, buffer_data + *offp, count); `


Something must also be wrong with my_write:
`copy_from_user(buffer_data + *offp, buff, count);`

Comment: What sort of data structure is the the driver intended to model? Something like a random access block of data, so something like a pipe?

Comment: More like a simple file that you can write to and read from.
For example our tests cases script would write "hello" to the device. Then read from the device and expect in return the same number of bytes that you just wrote

Answer (score 0):

In my_read() you must not allow reading the buffer after current_count (after the point where initialized data ends) . If the requested count goes farther you must first trim the passed count. If the resulting count is <= 0, or if the offset is after current_count you must return 0 to indicate end of file.

Also you must return the trimmed count (which was really copied to the user).

I expect that you test with echo and cat. But if you test with your own code, by reading and writing in sequence, don't forget to reset the offset using lseek() between reading and writing.

As far as I can tell your code looks like a good start but the counts and file position management require some cleanup.